# Problems on selecting VALUE from multidimensional ARRAY created from CSV

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

So, I got a CSV file that I correctly import in PHP.

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=';')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}


echo '<pre>';
$product_csv = csv_to_array("$underfolder/$value");
print_r($product_csv);

echo '</pre>';
```

This works and give show as result:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array
      (
          [Name] => product name xyz
          [Description] => der trefa a as sadfse
          [TAGS] => tag1 tag2 tag3
          [360] => yes
          [VR] => no
      )

)
```

But how I echo a VALUE of  `$product_csv`? Like if I want to print out "product name xyz"? I tried with `echo $product_csv["0"]['Name']` but without any results...

`var_dump(array_keys($product_csv[0]));` gives me:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "Name" [1]=> string(11) "Description" [2]=> string(4) "TAGS" [3]=> int(360) [4]=> string(2) "VR" }
```

Comment: how is wordpress related to this issue?

Comment: `0` is an integer not a string so it would be: `$product_csv[0]['Name']`

Comment: You right. Is just that the code is running in a WP site. I remove it.

Comment: Post results of `var_dump($product_csv);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Done it. Updated the post

Comment: `var_dump(array_keys($product_csv));` or something else wrong that's not shown.

Comment: I'm curious about those two rogue `}` at the end of the top snippet.  Is this being run inside of a loop or something?

Comment: @AbraCadaver
var_dump(array_keys($product_csv));
RESULTS
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: @PatrickQ yes is running inside a FOREACH loop.

Comment: Sorry I must be tired `var_dump(array_keys($product_csv[0]));`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for your time!! 
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Name"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Description"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "TAGS"
  [3]=>
  int(360)
  [4]=>
  string(2) "VR"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in your `var_dump(array_keys($product_csv[0]));` output: `string(7) "Name"`, there must be 3 invisible characters as `Name` is only 4 characters not 7.

Attempt to trim them by replacing:

```
$header = $row;
```

With:

```
$header = array_map('trim', $row);
```

It could very well be a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  If you are creating this file then check the editor to see if it saves it with a BOM, and if possible disable it.

Comment: You're great, it was a BOM problem. 
I've noticed before that the problem was just with the `Name` field, with the other VALUES it was working. Thank you !